# What do you think are the causes?

Tags: wh-questions

What do you think **are** the causes?

What do you think the causes **are**?

I've heard both are true but the former is more popular.

Is this true? and if so, could you tell me the reason?

What grammar should I read to learn more about this?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What do you think are the causes?
> 2. What do you think the causes are?

These two questions have the same fundamental content, because they derive from  canonical declarative forms which have the same fundamental content:

> 1. You think X are the causes.
> 2. You think the causes are X.

The particular kind of predication employed in the subordinate clause here is like a mathematical equation: *are* is equivalent to **=** and the subject and predicate complement are identical.

> <sub>subj</sub>**X** = **the causes**<sub>predc</sub> *has the same meaning as*
>   <sub>subj</sub>**the causes** = **X**<sub>predc</sub>

I prefer the second version, *...the causes are*, because this places *x*, the matter you are asking about, in the predicate, which is the ordinary 'new information' position.

Note that this will not be the case with verbs other than *BE*, or with *BE* when it predicates something other than an identity.

> ☑ How big do you think his head is? ... You think his head is big. *but not*
>   ☒ How big do you think is his head? .... You think big is his head.